# _GSRegisterPurpleNamedPortInPrivateNamespace - App Store Crash (code attached)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, app-store

After 3.5 months on the App Store, I got my first crash report. This was discovered in iTunes Connect this morning. Within XCode, I went to Window > Organizer > Crashes > [App + App build that reported the crash].

**The first screenshot below is the crash report GUI:**
[image: Crash Log from XCode Organizer]

**I then clicked "Open in Project"** *(which was the Call to Action button from the previous screenshot)*

"Open in Project" brought me into XCode. Here's what the Debug Navigator looks like:

[image: Debug Manager]

Clicking on "7 main" brings up this class:
[image: class]

```
class UIButtonScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if (view.isKind(of: UIButton.self)) {
            return true
        }

        return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)

    }

}
```

I'm guessing that's the code that may be responsible for causing the crash. The purpose of this UIScrollView subclass is to handle the scrolling (while the users finger scrolls directly on a button) of a long list of buttons within a small scrollview in the App.

The crash report stated it happened on an iPhone 5s running 9.1. I tried everything possible to reproduce the crash in that simulator, and could not. It runs flawless for me.

**Why / what caused the _GSRegisterPurpleNamedPortInPrivateNamespace crash? Am I looking in the wrong spot to try debugging my code (UIButtonScrollView)?** I want to nip this in the butt before it happens to another user. Any guidance on my above questions is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode is displaying the wrong file here. The crash is occurring in internal initialization code, before any of your code runs. (Specifically, it is occurring in the `main()` function, which is automatically generated by Swift when it sees the `@UIApplicationMain` attribute.)

Chances are that this crash is a random error, possibly caused by a hardware problem on the user's device. If you've only seen it happen once, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: That's a breath of relief. Question though - How do you know that Xcode is displaying the wrong file?

 So you're saying that this crash occurred before the user was even able to open the application? (due to possible hardware issue)

Comment: You clicked on the call frame for `main`, and the code you ended up looking at isn't `main`. Not sure how you ended up looking at that, but it doesn't match the call stack at all -- must be some sort of weird Xcode bug.

Comment: Have the exactly same error in iOS 10.3.2 with our game made with Unity... I just ignore it for now, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on Xcode 9.2 today on a device and not the simulator. I ended up quitting all of my Xcodes (I have 9.2 and 9.3 due to some irrelevant compatibility issues) and when I restarted it worked.

Before just quitting all my Xcodes it worked